# Error creating xml file in android

Tags: android

Error while creating Xml file.

Exception raised during rendering:-

```
android.widget.CheckBox cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center_vertical">
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/bcheck" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="false">   
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
     android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" 
     android:text="Test" 
     android:focusable="false">  
</TextView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:clickable="true" ></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout></CheckBox>
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should paste java code...

Comment: and paste even logcat plz

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/bcheck" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false"> 
    </CheckBox>  
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="left|center_vertical" 
         android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" 
         android:text="Test" 
         android:focusable="false">  
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:clickable="true" ></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u explain what edits u have made and explain how it works ??

Comment: CheckBox is not a ViewGroup...it is a View. ViewGroup's can contain other views inside, like LinearLayout.

Comment: You have just misplaced the </checkbox> view at the ending of the xml, I have replaced it in correct place.